# Team Services team's backlog not showing tasks

Tags: azure-devops

I'm currently using Team Services with multiple teams but am having an issue with displaying tasks on the specific team's backlog.

I have created two teams (Portal & Core) with there own area.

I have created a story and have set it to the root area.

To complete this story requires effort by both teams. I have created a task for the Portal team and set it to their area and another task for the Core team and have set it to their area.

If I look at the teams backlog I cannot see the task for them (I have set Show Parents).

Should I be able to split tasks of a story across multiple teams?

Thanks

Comment: Do you solve this question by Daniel's answer?

Comment: Not really, I don't fully agree based on other responses to similar questions (such as the one I linked to in the comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to achieve this directly. But there is an alternative method for this, refer to the steps below for details:

1. Go to the "Work\Area" settings of the root project and add a new child area for example "TwoTeams".
   [image]
2. Go to the "Work\Area" settings of the child projects(Portal & Core) and add "CrossTeam\TwoTeams" area to them.
   [image]
3. Assign the user story to "CrossTeam\TwoTeams" area.

Now you will see the User Story and Tasks on the teams backlog like following:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, that has done the trick. Although this is possible, should I be doing it this way? From other related questions the story should be from a customer POV (so for example I want to log in) which would require work on front & back end so potentially multiple teams so makes me think I should do it this way. But The fact that Team Services doesn't support it properly makes me doubt myself.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you *should* be able to is one thing, which is a broader topic. Whether you *can* is a different question, one with an exact, factual answer: You can't.

A user story is intended to be a discrete unit of work that is completed by a single cross-functional team. If you have multiple teams working on one user story, chances are good that the user story is too large and should be decomposed further.

Comment: That's what I was wondering but I saw other questions (such as http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/240325/should-a-user-story-be-shared-between-developers) which suggests that a story is from a customer perspective so doesn't matter if it requires work from front-end and back-end team. If the story is to enable a user to login then is does require both teams

Comment: An Agile team is supposed to be cross functional.